# How to delete everything in node redis?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I want to be able to delete all the keys. Is there a way to flush all in node redis?

Redis client:

```
client = redis.createClient(REDIS_PORT, REDIS_HOST);
```

Comment: need a working sample code for this question.
Tried the mentioned answers, but they are not working.

Comment: If you are using node-redis then you should use the redis built in function: `client.FLUSHDB();`

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Perhaps [flushdb](http://redis.io/commands/flushdb) or [flushall](http://redis.io/commands/flushall) are options that you can look into.

In Node, with the client, these look like this:

```
client.flushdb( function (err, succeeded) {
    console.log(succeeded); // will be true if successfull
});
```

Comment: `flushdb` will flush keys from selected database, `flushall` - will flush keys from *all* databases.

Comment: how to specify db ?

Answer (score 18):

Starting from **Redis 4.0.0** or greater, you can now delete all keys asynchronously using [`FLUSHALL [ASYNC]`](https://redis.io/commands/flushall#codeflushall-asynccode-redis-400-or-greater). Using the client, just pass the `'ASYNC'` option to the command like so:

```js
client.flushall('ASYNC', callback);
```

---

Use [`FLUSHDB [ASYNC]`](https://redis.io/commands/flushdb) to flush keys from a selected database. Use [`FLUSHALL [ASYNC]`](https://redis.io/commands/flushall) to flush keys from all databases.